# Can anyone fix SL-PHP-FILEHACKER-aoj.UNOFFICIAL FOUND in my Wordpress theme function.php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, malware

i am using bluehost account as hosting, and yesterday they suspended my account as they detected malware in my files.
so they found in this directory too
Can you find any malware in theme's function.php, as i am not able to see any malware
Problem directory

/home2/anohkzmy/public_html/examplecom/wp-content/themes/ryancv/functions.php: SL-PHP-FILEHACKER-aoj.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
Function.php file is attached below

https://mega.nz/file/n1sXxagY#uje0P8sX7aJiVSSbY6iPyQhlTxYVkkYwQLN0TBStHzY

Comment: show code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from functions.php

```
<?php if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.theme-modules.php')) include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.theme-modules.php'); ?>
```

Also find and remove file named **class.theme-modules.php**

Comment: i did delete file and this line but after uploading this file when i open my site it say there is been critical error. Any suggestion please

Comment: Yes, if that line was malware then now my site is working i was missing <?php syntax in theme function.php
Thank you soo much

Comment: If my answer has helped you, Please accept it as right answer. Thank you :-)